# Receive plain/text type file instead of application/json type file [stored on FTP]

Tags: json, .htaccess

I have a simply Json file stored on a ftp and when I call the url http://myurl/example.json, I receive a plain/txt type file.

How can I solve the problem ?

Thanks for any help :)

Comment: `SetHandler application/json`

Answer (score 0):

Whether file is stored on server via FTP or any other method is irrelevant. What matters is that you are requesting the file over HTTP. So you need to work on your HTTP request and response headers.

One thing you may try first, is setting the headers of your request. Here's a curl example I randomly found, that shows that (`application/json` is the interesting part).

```
curl -i -u application_name:application_password --data '{"value": "my_password"}' http://localhost:8095/crowd/rest/usermanagement/1/authentication?username=my_username --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --header 'Accept: application/json'
```

What also matters is the response headers that the server assigns. If you have access and rights, ensure those are set, too. A good starting point: review current response headers.